# Fetch mail attachment into SQL Server 2005 using IMAP

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, imap

I need to import data into my SQL Server 2005 from an e-mail datasource on an Exchange mail server. It means that when a mail is sent to a particular mail address I must retrieve the mail subject and the attached file and then I must import these data into my SQL Server 2005, using IMAP.

Can I do this with SSIS, or do I have to write a Windows Service in C# ?

Do I need to use an IMAP API library of some kind ?

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody is interested: I solved the problem myself using an open source IMAP library which I included in a Windows Service. I did not use SSIS anyway because SSIS in SQL Server 2005 does not support the IMAP interface.

The open source IMAP library is called "Koolwired.IMAP".

Here are some links that I found useful:

http://koolwired.com/solutions/solutions.aspx?id=30

http://sourceforge.net/projects/imapnet/

http://www.codeplex.com/imapnet/Thread/List.aspx

http://www.imap.org/